# How to run a scalar function over a length of time for multiple objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, calculated-columns

Hi I am trying to do an arithmetic calculation on a large amount of data using scalar valued functions. My source data is in the following format:

```
----------
ID  PriceDate   Type    Value
1   14/01/2018  Alpha   1.05
1   14/01/2018  Beta    1.07
2   14/01/2018  Alpha   1.03
2   14/01/2018  Beta    1.2
3   14/01/2018  Alpha   1.6
3   14/01/2018  Beta    1.5
1   15/01/2018  Alpha   1.24
1   15/01/2018  Beta    1.23
2   15/01/2018  Alpha   1.29
2   15/01/2018  Beta    1.1
3   15/01/2018  Alpha   1.16
3   15/01/2018  Beta    1.4
```

---

The complete dataset has 7million rows+ (1900  unique ID and dates from present back to 2011).
It is also the case that the dataset is not complete, an ID may have an alpha value but no beta value on a particular day or vica versa or non at all.

I am trying to calculate (alpha- beta)/beta for each individual date where an ID has both an alpha value and a beta value.

So far I have a function to do this for a particular value:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION instrument.Calculate (@PriceDateF datetime, @ID bigint)
RETURNS decimal(20,10)
AS
-- Returns ((Alpha-Beta)/Beta)
BEGIN

    Declare @BetaT decimal(20,10)
    Declare @AlphaT decimal(20,10)
    Declare @Result decimal (20,10)

    SELECT @BetaT = Value
    FROM ValueTable I
    WHERE I.PriceDate = @PriceDateF
    AND I.ID = @ID
    AND Type = 'Beta'

    SELECT @AlphaT = Value
    FROM ValueTable I
    WHERE I.PriceDate = @PriceDateF
    AND I.ID = @ID
    AND Type = 'Alpha'

    SELECT @Result = (@AlphaT - @BetaT)/@BetaT

RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

My question is, how do I run this function on the 'Value table' over time for each individual ID to get a result, (a-b)/b, on each day for each ID. I am not sure how I input the parameters and whether the function should loop through the data table or any other ways to do it. I am also unsure how to deal with the gaps in the data (where there are no values on some dates, or just a beta or alpha value).

Thanks very much :) 
I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: Tag the dbms you'er using. (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, a `join` might be simple enough:

```
select da.pricedate, da.id, da.value as alpha, db.value as beta,
       (da.value - db.value) / db.value
from data da join
     data db
     on da.pricedate = db.pricedate and da.id = db.id and
        da.type = 'Alpha' and
        db.type = 'Beta';
```

There is no need for a user-defined function.

I should note that you can also do this with aggregation:

```
select id, pricedate,
       max(case when type = 'Alpha' then value end) as Alpha,
       max(case when type = 'Beta' then value end) as Beta,
       (max(case when type = 'Alpha' then value end) -
        max(case when type = 'Beta' then value end)
       ) / max(case when type = 'Beta' then value end) as calculation
from data
group by id, pricedate;
```

Once again, a user defined function is not useful here.

Comment: The join worked perfectly. I just needed to add an additional condition on the join:

Comment: (Continued):

...AND db.ID = da.ID.

Other than that worked great. Thanks!